# Delete circle in WPF when dragging the slider backwards

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have a code which creates circles using a slider but I want it to delete it as well when dragging it backwards.
This is my code:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{          
    int marginLeft = (caPaper.Children.Count * 35);
    Random rd = new Random();

    byte r = (byte)rd.Next(0, 256);
    byte g = (byte)rd.Next(0, 256);
    byte b = (byte)rd.Next(0, 256);


    Ellipse newBall = new Ellipse();
    newBall.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r,g,b));
    newBall.Height = 30;
    newBall.Width = 30;
    newBall.Margin = new Thickness(marginLeft, 100, 0, 0);
    caPaper.Children.Add(newBall);
```

Comment: Remember the last value, and if the number is less, then remove the last child in caPaper.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: You are currently creating new Ellipse elements on every ValueChanged event, regardless whether it's a small or large change. Instead of that, you should use the Slider's Value as count of the Ellipses (set MinValue to zero and MaxValue to the maximum number of Ellipses). In the event handler cast `e.NewValue` to `int` to get the new desired count. If Children.Count is less than the desired count, create new elements, if it is larger, remove child elements as necessary. Use a horizontal StackPanel for `caPaper` to avoid the need for calculation margins.

Comment: This is pretty trivial. You might want to take a step back, grab a book called CLR Via C#, read it over the course of a day, and come back to this. You need to understand variable scoping (how to set a value that will be remembered inbetween method calls), how to retrieve the last element from a collection and how to remove that element from the collection.